# AngularJS doesn't display data

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding

I'm an absolute beginner in frameworks, particularly angular.
Please Give me a hint, why value in brackets are not displaying in the view. I'm looking for constructive criticism for AngularJS and Javascript, NOT for my skills as a computer scientist. This is a part 1 of Coursera "Full stack web development" course. Here is the code:

```
            <html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishCtrl">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                  <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                     <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                  </h2>
                                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <p>Put the comments here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

                app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

                    var dish = {
                        name: 'Uthapizza',
                        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                        category: 'mains',
                        label: 'Hot',
                        price: '4.99',
                        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',                           
                    };

                    this.dish = dish;

                });
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You can either change `this.dish =` to `$scope.dish =` or use `{{dishCtrl.dish.foo}}`.

Comment: I don't think authors of the course wanted me to use a scope 'cause it is in the next week. The second one I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when use controller-as so you should add dishCtrl before your data
 . like this

```
 {{dishCtrl.dish.name}}
```

```js
 var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

                app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

                    var dish = {
                        name: 'Uthapizza',
                        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                        category: 'mains',
                        label: 'Hot',
                        price: '4.99',
                        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',                           
                    };

                    this.dish = dish;

                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

                <div ng-app="confusionApp" class="container">
                    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishCtrl">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dishCtrl.dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dishCtrl.dish.name}}
                                  <span class="label label-danger">{{dishCtrl.dish.label}}</span>
                                     <span class="badge">{{dishCtrl.dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                  </h2>
                                    <p>{{dishCtrl.dish.description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <p>Put the comments here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: thank's for help, I still misunderstood much things angular basics

Comment: it is better use conroller-as as you use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try [avoiding scope soup](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html) by changing `this.dish = dish` to `$scope.dish = dish` in your controller.

A better solution is to use the controllerAs, in you case `dishCtrl`, as follows `{{dishCtrl.dish.description}}`.